# Tool jq works differently on windows and Linux?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, jq

Below is the file content in Json

```
{
  "FD_sfdsdf:ClientMasterBaseUrl": "http://example.com",
  "FD_fsdfs:CommonAPIBaseUrl": "http://example.com",
  "FD_sdfsadfsdf:Secret": "sdfsdf"
}
```

Command:

`cat fd.json| jq -r 'to_entries[] | "setx \(.key) \"\(.value)\""'`

which I run in windows CMD.

Output:

`setx FD_sfdsdf:ClientMasterBaseUrl "http://example.com"`

Above is the output desired which I am getting in MAC and Linux but the same command doesn't work in windows.

Error:

```
'"setx \(.key) \"\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: How doesn't the command work? What output do you get?

Comment: I get this error
`'"setx \(.key) \"\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. `

Comment: You must obey the respective shell quoting rules/syntax.

Comment: I *guess* in CMD single-quotes do not really quote, double-quotes kinda do. Sometimes it may appear single-quotes work, only because programs receive their arguments as one long string and need to do word splitting and quote removal by themselves; so supporting single-quotes is possible *at this stage* if the program supports them. But before this happens, in your case CMD sees unquoted `|`, as if you wanted to *pipe* to `"setx …`. By today standards of \*nix shells, CMD is manure.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760545/escape-double-quotes-in-parameter . But a comment tells this might still depend on the Windows parsing library used by the command (here that would be jq): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760545/escape-double-quotes-in-parameter#comment28290139_15262019

Comment: I found `jq  -r "to_entries[] | """set "\(.key)=\(.value)"""" "` works perfectly for me in windows and i get the below output 

`set FD_sfdsdf:ClientMasterBaseUrl=http://example.com`
But I want value in double quotes

Comment: Do you  really need to use `cat` and `jq` tools?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Do not use **`:`** to compose variables names, this character is used inside/next to the variable name for several actions, **[see who here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)**

**2.** If the goal is to define a variable getting the strings from your `.json` file, you could just use cmd...

---

- In your bat/cmd file:

  ```bat
  @echo off & cd /d "%~dp0"

  for /f tokens^=1-4delims^=^:^"^,^  %%i in ('
       type file.json^|find /i "FD_sfdsdf"')do setx FD_sfdsdf_%%~j "\"%%~k:%%~l\""
  ```
- In your command line:

  ```bat
  for /f tokens^=1-4delims^=^:^"^,^  %i in ('type file.json^|find /i "FD_sfdsdf"')do setx FD_sfdsdf_%~j "\"%~k:%~l\""
  ```

---

- Outputs:

  [image]
- **Obs.: 1.** You need two spaces (**<kbd>space</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>**), one is used as a delimiter along with the other characters, and the other is in respect of the *`for /f`* loop syntax:

  `for /f tokens^=1-4delims^=^:^"^,^spacespace%%i`
- **Obs.: 2.** For double quotes just add `\"` and being escaped in the windows registry.:

  `...)do setx FD_sfdsdf_%%~j "\"%%~k:%%~l\""`